# Rails: button to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a better/cleanier way to write the following in rails:

```
@next_user = @users[@users.index(@user) + 1]
if (@next_user)
    button_to "Next User", click_url(:id => @next_user.id);
else
    button_to "Next User", {}, :disabled => true;   
end
```

I have tried

```
@next_user = @users[@users.index(@user) + 1]
button_to "Next User", click_url(:id => @next_user.id), :disabled => !@next_user;
```

But the application throws an exception when reaching the last element of the array.

I just want to know if there is a better way to achieve the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it's much simpler but this should take care of the exception.

```
@next_user = @users[@users.index(@user) + 1]
button_to "Next User", @next_user.nil? ? {} : click_url(:id => @next_user.id), :disabled => !@next_user;
```

Comment: If you remove the .nil? and reverse the operands of the ternary operator it looks simpler, thanks.